# Could not find method bundle()

Tags: android, gradle, android-app-bundle

I am trying to build appbundle in my project. I follow steps from official guide but getting following error on gradle sync. What can be wrong?

```
   * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyProject'.
    > Could not find method bundle() for arguments [build_4ng76ykxfhsfa1nuepa3fikmu$_run_closure5$_closure28@6448fs70] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
```

I added `android.enableAapt2=true` to gradle.properties file and run ./gradlew --stop

Comment: Can you please check , gradle plugin version. I think plugin related issue will be there.

Comment: @YogeshRathi thanks, completely forgot about gradle plugin

Comment: Good luck , happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed plugin version, If someone face same stacktrace.
Please check plugin version.

> Update Android gradle plugin version to `3.2.0` or later
>
> ```
> classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the task you're looking for is `bundleRelease` or `bundleDebug`.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It was gradle plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyAlias 'xxxxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxxx'
        storeFile file('xxxxx')
        storePassword 'xxxxx'
    }
    releaseConfig {}
}
```

you maybe lost signingConfigs {} which is the curly braces, i add this then anything is well.

you may try it